# A group homomorphism is injective if and only if the identity of $G$ is the only element mapped to the identity in $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> A group homomorphism is injective if and only if the identity of $G$ is the only element mapped to the identity in $H$

I have the first direction.

$"\Rightarrow"$: $f$ is an injective homomorphism. Suppose $f(a)=1_H, a \ne 1_G$. Then $f(a1_g)=f(a)f(1_g)=1_H$, since $f$ is given to be a homomorphism. This implies $f(1_G)=1_H$, so $a$ must equal $1_G$ otherwise $f$ is not injective, a contradiction.

But not sure how to show the other direction, is it also by contradiction?

Comment: Four out of your last seven questions have answers, but none have been accepted. Please consider accepting answers to your previous questions, or at least clarify why you haven't accepted an answer, before asking more questions.

Comment: Note that you can accept an answer by clicking underneath the downvote arrow for that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose $f(a)=f(b)$. What must $f(ab^{-1})$ be? So if $a\not=b$, what does this mean about $f^{-1}(1_H)$?

Comment: $f(ab^{-1})=f(a)f(b^{-1})=f(b)f(b^{-1})...=f(b)f(b)^{-1}=1_H$ a contradiction, since $f(1_G)=1_H$ uniquely, right?

Comment: Well, you need the assumption that $f$ is injective to conclude that this is a contradiction if $a\not=b$, but yes.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a direct proof:

- If $f$ is a homomorphism, then $f(1_G)=1_H$. If $f$ is also injective, no other $g \in G$ can be sent to $1_H$.
- If $f(g_1)=f(g_2)$, then $1_H = f(g_2)f(g_1)^{-1}= f(g_2 g_1^{-1}) $. If $f$ only sends $1_G$ to $1_H$, then $g_2 g_1^{-1}=1_G$ and so $g_2=g_1$, which means that $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you've shown that if $f$ is an injection, then the identity in $G$ is the only element mapped to the identity in $H$.

To show the converse, you need to show that if $G$ is the only element mapped to the identity, then the homomorphism $f$ is injective. The way I would do it is directly.

We want to show the definition of injective holds; that is, show $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $a=b$. We'll suppose there were two elements mapped to the same place; say $f(a)=f(b)=x\in H$. Then consider what that tells you about the element $ab^{-1}$, and where it is mapped. This should tell you $a=b$, and we are finished!

Comment: I wrote the wrong arrow.

Comment: Gotcha. Edited so I'm no longer pointing it out! Sorry, I should have probably suggested it as an edit or comment - just learning correct Math Stack etiquette.

Comment: no worries, and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

For the first direction you can just use the injectivity of the homomorphism and the fact that by definition of a group homomorphism we must have that $f(1_G)=1_H$.

For the other direction assume that $ker(f)$ is more than just the identity, and that the group homomorphism is injective, then reach a contradiction.